# .length cannot be applied to the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `length` because I need the length of state, but there is an error called *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')*. `SetName` and `name` are declared by the parent component, but they change every time they receive letters as input. I want to get a true value if there are more than one letter in the input, but what's wrong? I'd appreciate if you let me know

**File:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import geryO from '../../resources/images/img/greyO.png'

const InputWrap = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);
  border-radius: 3px;
 
  .inputInput {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    border: 0;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 9px 0 7px 8px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .userIdCheckGreyO {
    display: ${props=>props.isFocus===true&&props.isString?'flex':'none'};
    align-items: center;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 8px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }


`

function SignUpNameInpu({name, setName}) {

  //isfocused? 
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

  //change true/false if input is focused
  const inputFocus = () => {
    setIsFocus(false)
  }

  const inputNotFocus = () => {
    setIsFocus(true)
  }

  //check length of string
  const [isString, setIsString] = useState(false)
  
  //(maybe this function is wrong)
  const stringLengthCheck = (name) => {
    if(name.length>0) {
      setIsString(true)
    }
  }
  
  console.log('stringLength :', isString)

  return (
    <InputWrap isFocus={isFocus} isString={isString}>
      <label>
        <span>
          <input 
            onFocus={()=>{inputFocus(); stringLengthCheck();}} 
            onBlur={inputNotFocus} 
            className='inputInput' 
            value={name} 
            onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}}>
          </input>
        </span>
      </label>
      <div className='userIdCheckGreyO'>
        <span>
          <img src={geryO} alt='greyO' />
        </span>
      </div>
    </InputWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUpNameInpu;
```

Comment: name state is initializated as string? `const [name, setName] = useState('')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `stringLengthCheck` function with no arguments in `onFocus` event but it expects one. Just call the function with provided argument like `stringLengthCheck(name)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't understand well, which part of the code should I modify?

Comment: `onFocus={()=>{inputFocus(); stringLengthCheck(name);}}` - modify `onFocus` event like this

Comment: You are welcome, you can now pick an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be passing an argument into `stringLengthCheck`, so when it is called, `name` is undefined.

Try removing the `name` argument in the function declaration for `stringLengthCheck`, it seems to be losing reference to the `name` coming from the props.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling stringLengthCheck function with no arguments in onFocus.You need to pass one argument in **stringLengthCheck** function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't understand well, how should I pass argument?

Comment: You need to pass one argument in stringLengthCheck function. You can use this onFocus={()=>{inputFocus(); stringLengthCheck(name);}}